# Golang Portable ("thumbdrive edition") for windows

Tags: go

Do Golang has Portable edition on windows , something like Strawberry Perl portable edition https://strawberryperl.com/releases.html , or git Portable ("thumbdrive edition") , that you can download Go as zip file on windows and extract it and work with it ?

also on this site : https://go.dev/dl/ i see to files MSI and ZIP what is the exact difference between them ?

Answer (score 2):

I just download the zip file from the downloads page https://go.dev/dl/

Then I just alias go to the {unzippedDir}/bin/go.exe